# SharePoint 2016 - Add Direct Line chat bot in Master Page to make it available in all the pages

Tags: botframework, master-pages, direct-line-botframework, sharepoint-2016

I want to make my Direct line chat bot (using MS bot framework v4 - c# code ) to be available in all pages of my SharePoint 2016 on premises site, I'd a thought to adding the script to my site's master page so that it will be available in all the pages of my SharePoint site.

Before heading to that plan, i want to get some expert ideas on the following,

1. Is that a good idea or is there any other better idea.
2. If anyone successfully achieved it, i want to know how it affects
   the SharePoint **performance**, since my chat bot's UI is customized
   using Jquery, bootstrap, fontawesome..etc. Hence i've this
   performance doubt.
3. How easy is to revert the changes, if anythings goes wrong, since i've no test environment and i'm taking a risk of testing it in production.

please guide me with your ideas and experiences.

Answer (score 1):

1. I would recommend putting it in a SPFx web part (more dynamic, future ready) or just a script editor web part (depending on your need).
2. Performance would only be affected client-side. It's all going to be client side stuff anyhow. It won't affect the backend of SharePoint/server.

Comment: can you please help me with the required documents for developing SPFx webpart  in SP 2016 on prem